# Display specific property between related models in admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I have one model lets call it A. It has N number fields, something like that:

```
class A(models.Model)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have another model B, which is related to A 1:M

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Here is my admin.py about model B:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from project_apps.b_apps.models import B

admin.site.register(B)
```

So far so good, but in admin page, when i click on B model it shows me relation to A in that way:

A object(1), A object(2) etc. ( for example)

That is very confusing. How can i achieve to display A.name1, A.name2 etc. instead of A object(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was elementary.

```
class A(models.Model)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

And it solve it. Case solved!